# iOS - Set URL image to UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I m trying to set a `UIImage`(e.g. http://www.nhpdcve.org/images/b5.jpg) from server to `UINavigationBar`.
We can set it toolbar,but what about `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: you must give response if people give answer of your question.. :(

Comment: Thanks Nitin and Paras(for editing question and answer too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set Image with this bellow method

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

also get Image from URL using bellow method..

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {
    UIImage * result;

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return result;
}
```

and set this Image Direct to yourNavigatioBar like bellow..

```
[yourNavigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self getImageFromURL:yourStringURL] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; //// pass your string url insted of yourStringURL
```

Answer (score 1):

you can easily set image of `Navigationbar`.
if you want to image resolution is clear then your image size must be `320 x 45` set image like below code:-

**set image from resource folder like this way:-**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarLoc.png"];
                [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**you can also set image from URL like this way:-**

```
  NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.urimageur/com"];
                NSData *d =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:d];

                [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean as the background of your navigation bar?
Try

```
[yourNavigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Its image from url , not in bundle.